# How can i make a Healthbar the same width no matter the health?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to have a Healthbar(Canvas) above every enemies head, and display their health. What I want is the exact same width for every bar, no matter how much health the enemy has. If they have low health, the bar goes down fast, if they have high health the bar goes down slowly. Here's my script

```
public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MaxHealth;

    [Space]
    public RectTransform HealthBar;

    private float CurrentHealth;

    void Start()
    {
        CurrentHealth = MaxHealth;         
        HealthBar.sizeDelta = new Vector2(CurrentHealth, HealthBar.sizeDelta.y);
    }

    void Update() 
    {        
        // this is for other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: The `visual-studio` tag is reserved for questions *about* Visual Studio, not code questions that happen to be written using VS.

Comment: Use the % of their current health, you should know the size delta you want for example a size of 150.  your `currentHealth` value you are passing to the size delta would just be health/maxhealth * 150.

Comment: there is literally nothing in the script. what are you trying to show? The Empty UPDATE?

Comment: I suggest looking at using an image for the healthbar and the use fillAmount to change it's fullness.https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image-fillAmount.html